# C++ while statement, with nested if else

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have been having an issue getting the if else statement to properly work in the code.

I have everything else where I need it, just we are supposed to have multiple entries input and it just automatically uses the responses and the else statements do not work.

```
int main ()
{
   string dep = "Deposit";          
   string with = "Withdrawl";       
   string bal = "Balance";          

   char choice;                 

   cout << "PLease enter options A, B, C, or Q to quit.\n";
   cin >> choice;   

    switch (choice) //to make them all the same, same as using  toUpper
    {
       case 'a':

       case 'A':
          cout << "";
          break;

       case 'b':

       case 'B':
          cout << "";
          break;

       case 'q':

       case 'Q':
          cout << "";
          break;
    }

    int count = 1;

    while (count <= 4)
    {
       if (choice == 'a' || 'A' )
          cout << dep << endl;
       else if (choice == 'b' || 'B' )  
               cout << with << endl;            
            else if(choice == 'c' || 'C' )          
                    cout << bal << endl;            
                 else 
                    (choice !='a' && choice !='b' && choice !='c');

       cout << "that is invalid, PLease enter options A, B, C, or Q to    quit.\n";

       ++count ;
    }

    system ("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (choice == 'a' || 'A')` does not do what you think. You need `if (choice == 'a' || choice == 'A')`, etc. Note: you could also convert all input to upper or lower case to reduce the tests.

Comment: Also, `else (choice !='a' && choice !='b' && choice !='c');` is lacking an `if`, and shouldn't have `;` at the end for what you intend to accomplish there.

Comment: Finally, you don't read fresh user input in the loop. You just loop over the original input character four times.

Comment: Please use either `toupper` or `tolower` so you can convert the choice to upper or lower case and only make one comparison.  In your program that would eliminate this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the conditional statements like this:

```
if (choice == 'a' || choice == 'A' )
```

What you have will always result in the first conditional being met because 'A' is equal to decimal 65.

Comment: I recommend you review your reasoning and operator precedence.  If I use another collation sequence where `A` is not 0x41, would your reason still hold true?

Comment: I'm actually trying to remove my answer but the stack exchange app won't let me, and when I try to go to the site in a browser, the app crashes...

Comment: Also, to respond to your comment, `==` precedes `||`, and 'A' will always be equal to some integer greater than 0, so I don't see how my reasoning is in question here.

Answer (score -1):

`if(choice == 'a'||'A')`,the computers will run the `'a'||'A'` first,and it's return 1 (in bool) ,and then run the
`choice == 1`,according to your codes, there are no `choice == 1`,so the codes in if will not be run.

Comment: Actually, `==` has a higher precedence than `||`.